# What is more pythonic in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, coding-style, string-formatting

Which string implementation in python is more pythonic?

```
string += "<%s>%s</%s>%s" % (a, b, c, d)
```

or

```
string += '<' + a + '>' + b + '<'/' + c + '>' + d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String formatting is faster and more readable, always.

Consider using named parameters, and the more recent [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
"<{tag}>{value}</{tag}>{tail}".format(tag='foo', value='bar', tail='spam')
```

Comment: That function str.format() looks great for my script. Thank you